# how to get output in json format using php code

Tags: php, json

i have written the php code for getting web services 
my idea is if i give the book name the web services should return the book price for that i have written code

### service.php

```
 <?php 

 include 'lib/nusoap.php';   //load the library file
 include 'lib/fun.php';
 $server=new nusoap_server(); //create instance to the class
 $server->configureWSDL("demo","urn:demo");  //it will accept the two     parameters one name of the webservice,two namespace of the web service
   $server->register(
    "price",  //name of function
              array("name"=>'xsd:string'), //inputs
              array("return"=>"xsd:integer")  //outputs
    );
   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA :'';
   $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
 ?>
```

### client.php

```
 <?php
   require 'lib/nusoap.php'; 

       $client=new nusoap_client("http://localhost/demo/service.php?wsdl");
     $book_name ="abc";
   $price = $client->call('price',array("name"=>"$book_name"));
   if(empty($price))
  echo "book data not available";
 else
    echo $price;

    ?>
```

### fun.php

```
  <?php 

  function price($name){
   $details=array(

           'abc'=>100,
           'xyz'=>200 
          );
   foreach($details as $n=>$p)
    {
    if($name==$n)
        $price=$p;

    }
    return $price;
    echo json_encode($price);
    }
   ?>
```

when i run this code it is working fine ,if i check this on soaclient ,when i am giving book name as

```
 name: abc 
 it returning the value :100
```

i need this output in json format when i give book name.what code has to change please help me

Comment: `return` ends the current method / function, so your echo never runs. It will also never do more than one iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 return json_encode(["price"=>$price]);
```

visit for output : https://eval.in/582574

Answer (score 0):

you should modify in fun.php :

```
<?php 

  function price($name){
   $price = array();
   $details=array(

           'abc'=>100,
           'xyz'=>200 
          );
   foreach($details as $n=>$p)
    {
    if($name==$n)
        $price[$n]=$p;

    }
    return json_encode($price);  // <<<<<<<<<<<
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: check this https://eval.in/582574, output would be `100`, what you expect for json form with this code ?